# jasper ireport subreport variable or main report variable main report variable duplicate print

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new in jasper report, I used jasper ireport 5.6.0.

I have two reports main report or subreport and I returned variable value from subreport to the main report value successfully returned from subreport, but here is a problem I have faced:

When I have printed sub-report variable or sum in grand total with the main report, the main report variable total duplicate two print with subreport variable here below screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

---

```
> mian report


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="printBillReport" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" scriptletClass="com.reporter.jasper.ConvertToWord" uuid="bd072f9e-2dda-451a-b0a1-13e9f2aa0d3b">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\windows\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SteplizerElectronics\\src\\steplizerelectronics\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="cusID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select *from sale where cus_id=$P{cusID}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cat_name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="model_no" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cus_name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cus_id" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="user_id" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="comp_name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cus_cell" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="sel_price" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="qty" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="amount" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="payable" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="borrow" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="status" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="regdate" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="amount_1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{amount}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="qty_1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{qty}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="borrow_1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{borrow}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="payable_1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{payable}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="grandTotall" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <variable name="total_amount" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{amount}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="123" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="137" y="80" width="66" height="20" uuid="3b4ea294-f433-491e-9803-2c36e8092e59"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Manufactur:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <rectangle radius="10">
                <reportElement x="1" y="1" width="555" height="118" uuid="f86b54e6-471d-4395-acda-da815bae56ae"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="113" width="112" height="3" uuid="f3df3b93-035d-4379-8635-c5947bdd4f62"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[14-DS Main Bund Road, Near Chohan Road, Islam Pura, Lahore.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="310" y="97" width="1" height="19" uuid="fab4c957-2174-44a7-a773-945807f51b60"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="118" y="8" width="258" height="22" uuid="1bbc2106-275b-45be-ae87-cd4607dc8c04"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Audiowide" size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[AONE ELECTRONICS FACTORY]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="1" y="3" width="102" height="68" uuid="94d07030-0eae-424a-a92e-b2c80f63d49e"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\windows\\Desktop\\aone.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="11" y="71" width="48" height="16" uuid="52f2829b-19ca-4269-bec6-80bdb9951674"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Address:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="285" y="99" width="83" height="14" uuid="85f72593-8c79-49ec-81b1-a266a1fbe68e"/>
                <text><![CDATA[M/S]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="279" y="73" width="274" height="1" uuid="b0e7d11d-efc3-4833-a07b-bb5ffc4f3f63"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="279" y="74" width="1" height="44" uuid="c4a74d99-3a03-469d-972b-f4319ae837ec"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="396" y="-14" width="35" height="16" uuid="93706ffc-0443-4a0c-9a78-8ae0258beeca"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="142" y="89" width="136" height="30" uuid="30a5b94f-a0a3-44d1-8e81-b8d5bdc70719"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Automatic Voltage steplizer Regulators & UPS]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="373" y="7" width="177" height="31" uuid="088518ef-edd8-4c30-a126-e9514f1b13d2"/>
                <jr:barbecue xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" type="Code39 (Extended)" drawText="false" checksumRequired="false">
                    <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA[$F{cus_name}+$F{cus_id}]]></jr:codeExpression>
                </jr:barbecue>
            </componentElement>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="321" y="98" width="234" height="16" uuid="edbc7887-c6f6-4209-bcf3-68ad5be80ec8"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{cus_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="143" y="73" width="60" height="16" uuid="abaf5bdb-61f6-4148-92c8-eafe2e5e6a9e"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Steplizers]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="285" y="77" width="100" height="16" uuid="c440daa7-1411-4e51-9750-6531b35acbd4"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Credit Sale]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="27" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="1" y="0" width="552" height="26" uuid="ab9bb588-6c52-4e6f-858a-f64555e9c482"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="2" width="26" height="20" uuid="cee00939-18a0-43a9-8f7b-8ef37c3c8136"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="69" y="3" width="100" height="20" uuid="c5555982-8ed2-486b-9b20-c820ea2d6303"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[PARTICULARS]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="334" y="2" width="68" height="20" uuid="444d348c-5aec-47d9-9b8b-8a0df7d5d9cc"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[UNIT RATE]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="416" y="2" width="31" height="20" uuid="e03d0e0f-fee8-48f6-b649-d29122dae87b"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[QTY]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="452" y="2" width="88" height="20" uuid="4b3c8b66-6b26-4b2c-bfa4-58917ad61092"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Amount Rs]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="18" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="1" y="-1" width="1" height="18" uuid="46636ee5-05ef-4ed0-98b3-8b3cdb0e388b"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="50" y="-2" width="1" height="18" uuid="df3f7753-0f5e-4ff0-bf2c-a3ae8a1d29dc"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="325" y="-2" width="1" height="19" uuid="ff6ab656-efe5-47d2-b6cc-7560cef1f5f4"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="411" y="-1" width="1" height="18" uuid="c6ecd5da-b343-441e-983f-b2414fa30583"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="445" y="-1" width="1" height="18" uuid="0dabdb94-9868-4f7e-935a-0fa235ce0a13"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="553" y="-1" width="1" height="18" uuid="0bc274c2-5f26-4f5d-b68d-e21bc2c4c888"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="1" width="26" height="14" uuid="63a319b2-8afe-4318-bab9-878b61ad4a82"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="70" y="1" width="255" height="14" uuid="cf463437-6041-457b-800b-b7d4917676f6"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{cat_name}+",  "+$F{model_no}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00">
                <reportElement x="335" y="1" width="72" height="14" uuid="10d9300e-83f3-4942-836a-c547e02d8c7d"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{sel_price}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="417" y="1" width="32" height="14" uuid="d744148c-6afe-46dc-b14f-c1ba4d6859c0"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{qty}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00">
                <reportElement x="452" y="1" width="89" height="14" uuid="b1d2ce72-c35f-4507-bb93-6f3e06b80a00"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>


<line>
                <reportElement x="50" y="-26" width="1" height="26" uuid="465616a8-77d2-4347-9290-149936abb9e7"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="325" y="-28" width="1" height="26" uuid="704a8402-1a4e-42a0-9ce3-673c8a9bc69b"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="411" y="-26" width="1" height="26" uuid="e4128970-6640-4c7b-9677-6b349dbfa0da"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="445" y="-27" width="1" height="26" uuid="4a2e897b-cd91-4573-a76d-a4f32b4cd077"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="39" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="-21" y="9" width="599" height="30" backcolor="#333333" uuid="8634a9b7-fcf3-4881-82c3-6679dbc18552"/>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="141" y="15" width="244" height="12" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="274941d4-cc0e-4fb4-997b-382c827badc9"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Software Provided by  Ph# +923024712782]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="142" y="27" width="244" height="12" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="a4ff6425-a7f1-4fff-b0ab-a92da8a2dcb5"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[www.ultronhouse.com]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="434" y="18" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="d1d8921f-151b-44c9-8d12-4b82cb993ffe"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="514" y="18" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="f31b2a21-d3fd-470f-9527-f998b02be397"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                <reportElement x="-1" y="17" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="34d4b240-cfb4-41d0-af4e-815e9e099d74"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="315" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="326" y="0" width="228" height="80" uuid="51ca5430-c464-4742-a4d6-178c75f4f4f8"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="325" height="22" uuid="e65cff7a-3ed1-450f-bfa7-585c580cfe60"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <textField pattern="">
                <reportElement x="63" y="5" width="263" height="20" uuid="102cb181-c6f9-4bf5-98cc-50333c2f9efa"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.readNumber($V{amount_1})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="7" y="6" width="48" height="20" uuid="1d88c6eb-ba59-45f2-b1af-b5b1cf1634b0"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Ruppies:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="327" y="60" width="226" height="1" uuid="95c9a5f3-5fed-4813-8bc1-076f9b658c09"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="333" y="3" width="77" height="20" uuid="fd70b399-0bf9-4840-87b9-c398765cd363"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Total]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="334" y="22" width="77" height="20" uuid="494a0fe7-85be-4220-9959-fbf09672ac68"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[QTY]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="334" y="61" width="110" height="20" uuid="fcb0a54c-5ecb-4e49-b7f0-0cd819c89a6c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Grand Total]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00;#,##0.00-">
                <reportElement x="453" y="3" width="100" height="20" uuid="62437a3a-407d-46a6-9531-4c445ecd0c98"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font size="11" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{amount_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00;#,##0.00-">
                <reportElement x="454" y="22" width="100" height="20" uuid="65b192d8-375b-4f1b-b90e-7802d3fdb6eb"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font size="11" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{qty_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report" pattern="#,##0.00;#,##0.00-">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="456" y="62" width="100" height="20" uuid="87f1c4f0-44ec-42a4-9416-527113afb9ed"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{grandTotall}+$V{total_amount})-$V{total_amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="136" y="2" width="192" height="21" uuid="ffdec19a-5213-44a4-a6e4-a874bb2b6578"/>
                <subreportParameter name="cusID">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{cus_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="grandTotall" toVariable="grandTotall"/>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "printBill_subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="335" y="41" width="108" height="20" uuid="f4b88757-b2f9-4c43-abd2-1d458137016e"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Previous Balance]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report" pattern="#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)">
                <reportElement x="455" y="43" width="100" height="20" uuid="1ed3c932-ce63-4a21-9624-a60f22720620"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{grandTotall}-$V{amount_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="86" y="60" width="100" height="20" uuid="d38785b9-638e-4e10-a9e2-b664205694e1"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{total_amount}+1+$V{grandTotall})-$V{total_amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

> Sub-report

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="printBill_subreport" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="40d765ae-ceb6-47eb-a59b-aa232f876bb6">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="cusID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select *from ac_balance where cus_id=$P{cusID} and status='UnClear']]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cus_name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cus_id" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="sale_id" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="qty" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="payable" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="borrow" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="receiveable" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="total" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="status" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="regdate" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="borrow_1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{borrow}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="grandTotall" class="java.lang.Double">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{borrow_1}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="52" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

> Images

```
here below some screen shots of reports properties bellow.
[Sub-report Image1][1]
[main-report Image2][2]
[output print3][3]
[image4][4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqdi4.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7OoC.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6LG4.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQALD.png
```

Comment: What is you variable "grandTotall" supposed to do? The picture indicates it does nothing:
[$V{grandTotall}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3613i.png) Does it simply contain the return value from your subreport? If yes, then the error should be there, but not in your main report.

Comment: dear respected sir thanks for this response , i have tried and change one by one check variable all reset type but result is same.

Comment: could you provide more information, e.g. code snippet of your jrxml report and subreport.

Comment: GrandTotal variable return value from sub-report to in main report.

Comment: then the "miscalculation" happens there. Pls post your subreport or a code snippet.